# Fermat's Theorem on $p = a^2 + b^2$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have read that Fermat predicted that for an odd prime $p$, $p = a^2 + b^2$ iff $p = 1 \pmod 4$.

I heard that such a criterion could be possible for a given integer $n$ like

$p = a^2 + n b^2$

with some integers $a, b$. However, somebody told me that such criteria can be available only if $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ has its class number $1$. Actually, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ has its class number $1$.

Are there any concrete counter-examples for such $n$ where we have no crireria like above. In that case, i.e. when $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ has its class number bigger than $1$, what can be said?

Comment: You should have a look at Cox' book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$", where this question is discussed in detail. Your question is not "research level", so it will likely be closed.

Comment: @MichaelStoll While I don't think the question is particulary deep, or demonstrates much work, I do feel MO should remain a place where researchers can ask about things outside their comfort zone

Comment: @YemonChoi, not sure you will be notified of this, but i left some good examples in answer.

Comment: The real point is that for class number one it is easy since there will only be one class of quadratic forms (of the given discriminant) and so representation of primes by such forms is determined by the Legendre symbol alone. When the class number rises you have to discard certain classes determined by the Legendre symbol...and these are determined by the splitting of certain polynomials mod $p$.

Comment: @fretty, see my answer. This would appear to be your area: these are some of the very few places with examples completely worked out. In comparison, Cox gives, on page 88, Kronecker's `compositum' version for $x^2 + 31 y^2,$ as a degree six monic polynomial having at least one root. He does $x^2 + 14 y^2$ on page 115, leaves $x^2 + 17 y^2$ to be finished as an exercise.

Comment: As you probably know one can solve this problem for any $n$. The key observation is that $p = x^2 + ny^2$ is equivalent to $p$ splitting completely in certain ring class fields attached to the order $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$. One can calculate these explicitly for small $n$ (and the examples you give in your answer are exactly the defining polynomials). In general one can find these fields by adjoining torsion points of elliptic curves with complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$.

Comment: @fretty, thanks. Just noticed your comment, you did not begin with an at sign and my name so it was just random chance that I looked back here.

Comment: Ah, I forgot, sorry!

Comment: It sounds a little strange to say "Fermat predicted" a mathematical fact. If he predicted an eclipse, that's different.

Answer (score 2):

As in comment, the best explanation is in the book by Cox. I can give several examples, some of class number 3 and some of class number 4. So, for instance, a prime $p > 3, p \neq 23$ can be written as $x^2 + 23 y^2$ if and only if $(-92|p) = 1$ and $$  z^3 - z + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$ has three distinct solutions.

In the Cox book he does this one in full: So, for instance, a prime $p > 3, p \neq 7$ can be written as $x^2 + 14 y^2$ if and only if $(-56|p) = 1$ and $$  z^4 + 2 z^2 -7 \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$ has four distinct solutions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Useful examples (+1)

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks. There are also some nice examples in an appendix of an Henri Cohen book, but organized by discriminant rather than class number. The references in Cox give examples with huge coefficients in the monic polynomials, so having these lists matters... Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory, Henri Cohen either 1999 or 2000